# Javascript compatibility with safari 9

Tags: javascript, safari

I have problem with js on safari 9
My code:

```
const subscribeForm = document.querySelector('#subscribeForm');
    subscribeForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        fetch(this.action + '?action=subscribe&email=' + this[0].value + '&site=' +<? print $this->id_site ?>)
            .then((r) => {
                return r.json();
            })
            .then((r) => {
                this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<p>${r.response}</p>`)
            });

    });
```

Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'

Please give me some ideas
On other browsers all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) Safari 9 don't support arrow functions, use `function() {` instead. Also [template literals where added in 9.1](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals) same as [fetch](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) and [const](https://caniuse.com/#feat=const) was added in Safari 10, for fetch you can use polyfill like [unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch).

So your code should look like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/unfetch/polyfill"></script>
<script>
var subscribeForm = document.querySelector('#subscribeForm');
    subscribeForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        fetch(this.action + '?action=subscribe&email=' + this[0].value + '&site=' +<? print $this->id_site ?>)
            .then(function(r) {
                return r.json();
            })
            .then(function(r) {
                this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>' + r.response + '</p>');
            });

    });

</script>
```

You also need to do something with [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) it was added in Safari 10, you can try [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/1276030).

Comment: Please can you describe how use polyfill in my case.

Comment: I have error when use polyfill
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElementNS' of undefined